# How can I close an image shown to the user with the Python Imaging Library?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have several images which I would like to show the user with Python. The user should enter some description and then the next image should be shown.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, glob
from PIL import Image

path = '/home/moose/my/path/'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.png') ):
    im = Image.open(infile)
    im.show()
    value = raw_input("Description: ")
    # store and do some other stuff. Now the image-window should get closed
```

It is working, but the user has to close the image himself. Could I get python to close the image after the description has been entered?

I don't need PIL. If you have another idea with another library / bash-program (with subprocess), it'll be also fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `show` method "is mainly intended for debugging purposes" and spawns an external process for which you don't get a handle, so you can't kill it in a proper way.

With PIL, you may want to use one of its GUI modules , such as [`ImageTk`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagetk.htm), [`ImageQt`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imageqt.htm)  or [`ImageWin`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagewin.htm).

Otherwise, just manually spawn an image viewer from Python with the `subprocess` module:

```
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.png')):
    viewer = subprocess.Popen(['some_viewer', infile])
    viewer.terminate()
    viewer.kill()  # make sure the viewer is gone; not needed on Windows
```

Comment: Hi larsmans, thats exactly what I've searched for. Could you please make the input of Popen to a list (adding [])? Without it, it doesn't work. Thanks also for mentioning ImageTk and ImageQt, I'll have a look at them.

Comment: @moose: yes, forgot the `[]`, sorry.

Comment: how would I use preview on OSX as `some_viewer`?

Comment: documentation links are broken

Answer (score 18):

[psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) can get the pid of the `display` process created by `im.show()` and kill the process with that pid on every operating system:

```
import time

import psutil
from PIL import Image

# open and show image
im = Image.open('myImageFile.jpg')
im.show()

# display image for 10 seconds
time.sleep(10)

# hide image
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "display":
        proc.kill()
```

Comment: @IDelgado psutil should work under OS X. Please describe your problem on the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues).

Comment: @Bengt After `proc.name` a method so you can call it  like `proc.name()` and only then will works. Please fix it and you and you get a vote up.

Comment: @IDelgado see the previous comment.

Comment: @GyörgySolymosi @IDelgadoYes, in newer versions of psutil `proc.name` is a method rather than a string property. If one checks for the name property, the script exits without effect, because they look something like this: `<bound method Process.name of <psutil.Process(pid=14358,name='display') at 19774288>>` Thanks for pointing this out, I updated my answer. Hopefully, nobody will trip over that in the future.

Comment: In macOS, proc.name() will be 'Preview'.

Answer (score 6):

I've modified [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/521918-pil-and-tkinter-to-display-images/) before to do some image work in Python.  It uses `Tkinter`, so it doesn't require any modules besides PIL.

```
'''This will simply go through each file in the current directory and
try to display it. If the file is not an image then it will be skipped.
Click on the image display window to go to the next image.

Noah Spurrier 2007'''
import os, sys
import Tkinter
import Image, ImageTk

def button_click_exit_mainloop (event):
    event.widget.quit() # this will cause mainloop to unblock.

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.bind("<Button>", button_click_exit_mainloop)
root.geometry('+%d+%d' % (100,100))
dirlist = os.listdir('.')
old_label_image = None
for f in dirlist:
    try:
        image1 = Image.open(f)
        root.geometry('%dx%d' % (image1.size[0],image1.size[1]))
        tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
        label_image = Tkinter.Label(root, image=tkpi)
        label_image.place(x=0,y=0,width=image1.size[0],height=image1.size[1])
        root.title(f)
        if old_label_image is not None:
            old_label_image.destroy()
        old_label_image = label_image
        root.mainloop() # wait until user clicks the window
    except Exception, e:
        # This is used to skip anything not an image.
        # Warning, this will hide other errors as well.
        pass
```

Comment: It requires ImageTK. But I've just found the proper Ubuntu-Package: sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk. Am I missing something or isn't it possible for the user to give an input? I wanted to close the current window and open the next (or simply open the next in the current window) without any other user interaction than writing a description (finisihing with enter).

Comment: ImageTK should come with PIL...   You can modify the window and tack on a text field and button if you like.  My `Tkinter` is very old, usually I use `wx`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv-python library to show images and close all the windows opened after.

```
import cv2
# read image 
image = cv2.imread('path to your image')
# show the image, provide window name first
cv2.imshow('image window', image)
# If you do not add it, you will see just an image filled with gray. [1]
cv2.waitKey()
# and finally destroy/close all open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[opencv shows gray window]
[1]: [OpenCV Shows Gray Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894451/opencv-shows-gray-window)