# Opencv window does not refresh itself at start

Tags: python, opencv

I have a trivial but annoying problem when I run following python code on Windows 7 64 bit OS.

```
import sys
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("D:\test.tif")
...
cv2.imshow("origin",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Everything is fine except that I got gray window at first. If I move the window, then it gets refreshed and display correct image. Is this problem due to my poor graphics card, a bug in OpenCV, or something else?

I have all 64 bit version of OS, python, opencv and numpy.

Comment: What platform are you on? I can't reproduce it on OS X.

Comment: @Aurelius Thanks for your comment. Updated my question accordingly. So it might be hardware or OS issue, I guess.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8894451/1601291) might be describing the same problem.