# Unable to display bounding rectangles around contours in OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, bounding-box

I have written this code to draw rectangular boxes around contours drawn in an image, however on running, I get everything right except the boxes, which I don't see at all. What's the error?

```
for cnt,heir in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt);
    cv2.rectangle(im2,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.drawContours(im2, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 2);   
cv2.imshow("Contours",im2);
```

PS. I use OpenCV 3.1.0 and Python 2.7

**EDIT:** I tried iterating through each contour and in order to check it I modified the code as follows:

```
for cnt,heir in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    print ('Contour Area:',cv2.contourArea(cnt));
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt);
    print (x,y,h,w)
    cv2.putText(im2,'worm',(x+w,y+h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA);
    cv2.rectangle(im2,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2);
```

I printed the contour area for each, the values of (x,y,w,h) for each and putting text "worm" for each contour and drawing the rectangular boxes around each contour. However I get just 1 output:

[image: Output for edited code]

for an image like:

[image: Source Image]

I need to display the text "worm" at each of the worm-like creature. However I just get it once. What are the issues?

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables (ie. `print(contours)`) and which part of code is executed (ie. `print("I'm inside for-loop")`). Maybe OpenCV returns empty list with `contours` BTW: OpenCV if can't do something doesn't raise error but returns `None` and you don't know that there is a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137511/python-opencv-drawcontours-does-not-show-anything - they use different color because `(0,255,0)` is invisible on their image.

Comment: @furas This is what I get : http://i.imgur.com/dSS3YRy.png - A very large list of nested arrays with some numbers. Also, I changed the colour, doesn't work !

Comment: did you check  what you have in `(x,y,w,h)` ? maybe you have `w=0, h=0`

Comment: can you upload the image you are working with? and what are you trying to detect?

Comment: @furas please see the edit

Comment: @JeruLuke please see the edit

Comment: if `contours` has more elements but `hierarchy` has only one element then `zip(contours, hierarchy)` will return only one pair `cnt,heir`

Comment: your area has size `w=1, h=1` so you may not see this rectangle.

Comment: @furas I see! Okay I'll try working through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to use below code to draw rectangles on the contours detected. Hope it helps.

```
for contour in contours:
    # get rectangle bounding contour
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    # draw rectangle around contour on original image
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,255),2)
```

Comment: coincidentally I just tried by removing the hierarchy part - an it does work! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply write:

```
for c in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c);
    cv2.putText(im2,'worm',(x+w,y+h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA);
    cv2.rectangle(im2,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2);

cv2.drawContours(im2, contours, -1, (255,255,255), 2);   
cv2.imshow("Contours",im2);
```

As suggested by **furas**, zip(contours,hierarchy) will return only one pair if hierarchy has only one. In this case a simple loop over **contours** list works.