# Draw contours correctly on the image (OpenCV/Python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, edge-detection

I am trying to draw contours around my test image. I am using canny edge detection in the background.

The `findContours` method works fine for my image but when I try to do `drawContours` method on that image. It does not show anything.

Here is what I have tried

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('/path/to/image.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
cv2.imshow("blurred", blurred)

canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 150)

(_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

print "Contours in the image, %d" % (len(cnts))

shape = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(shape.copy(), cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Edges", shape)
```

From what I gather from the docs, the fourth argument to the method `drawContours` would be used to specify the colour of the edge to be drawn over. But it does not show anything for instead of the green edge that I am expecting.

`len(cnts)` returns 2 for me

Here is the image I am trying it out with

[image: Here is the image that I trying it out with]

I am using opencv version 3.0.0

Relevant [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22137511/3834059)

**EDIT**: After changing the 3rd argument for `cv2.findContours()` to `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`, it is still not showing the final green edges(or any colour for that matter) on the final `cv2.imshow("Edges", shape)` image. Here is what I get from the canny edge image

[image]

Comment: Try with `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`

Comment: @ZdaR please check the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the last to lines of your code to:

You are already storing a copy of `image` in `shape`

```
shape = image.copy()
```

So why do you use `shape.copy()` in `cv2.drawContours()` again?

Replace it as follows:

```
cv2.drawContours(shape, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Edges", shape)
```

**NOTE:** You already have copied the image once, so use it to draw the contours. You don't have to use a copied version of the copied image.

This is what you get as a result:

[image]