# Image always renders as a gray box

Tags: python, opencv

When I load a set of image files into a list and try to display one, it always renders as a gray box.The images are not gray boxes. The size of the image window displayed by openCV varies with the size of the actual image on file.

```
import cv2
import glob
import random

def loadImages(path):
    
    imdir = path
    ext = ['png', 'jpg', 'gif']    # Add image formats here
    
    files = []
    [files.extend(glob.glob(imdir + '*.' + e)) for e in ext]
    #print("files", files)
    
    images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in files]
    return images

images = loadImages("classPhotos/")
print(str(len(images)), "images loaded")
#print(images)
cv2.imshow("image", random.choice(images))
tmp = input()
```

[image: The image looks like this]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV Shows Gray Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894451/opencv-shows-gray-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this 2 lines after `cv2.imshow("image", random.choice(images))` to make it work properly.

```
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

- `cv2.imshow` shows the image instantly and then doesn't show it.
- `cv2.waitKey` waits for a specific time/ keeps showing the image.

  - putting 0 as an argument makes it wait infinitely unless a key is pressed.
- `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`  helps close the window otherwise it gets stuck.

Comment: That fixed it! I assume it's a timing issue? Thanks!

Comment: Why does that make it work properly? Why does it change the image from a gray box to something different?

Comment: please don't answer questions that are obvious duplicates. just flag them as duplicates.

Comment: @nicomp imshow only delivers the data for the rendering. The actual screen rendering is performed in the waitKey call (or a pollKey call). See the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563

Comment: oh and the `destroyAllWindows` is redundant if the program ends anyway. in any case, that call merely removes existing windows, it **does not** cause images to show properly. nothing is "stuck" either. this entire answer is missing the mark. imshow does not "show and then doesn't show" anything. that's not how any of this works.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz, I agree about `destroyAllWindows` comment but I thought people should practice using it to avoid crashes. And how will flagging duplicate helps the person asking the question? Doesn't he need to know this? Do we need to be this specific/critical?

Comment: when the program ends, there will be no crash either way. if the program keeps running without needing to show anything, _then_ it's sensible to remove those windows. -- flagging a question as a duplicate _of another answered question_ is _good housekeeping_ on this site. this question's OP will see a link to the other question *and answer*, so they'll be helped. -- in this specific instance, _you_ benefit from criticism so you learn that what you offered as an answer is half-knowledge, and how things really work in OpenCV.

Comment: I understand. Should I delete the answer and flag the question? Also, should I search if the question is duplicate before answering?