# Alternative ways to show and close image in Python besides PIL or subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, python-imaging-library

I need to open an image for the user to view, wait a second, then close that image and open a new one from an array.

I have tried Image.open() in PIL however, I have read that we cannot close the image afterwards.

I have tried using subprocess, however, I for some reason cannot close the image. I have tried kill() and terminate() here, and have an open question for this here: [Close Image with subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195639/close-image-with-subprocess)
If you know what is wrong with my code using subprocess, I'd be happy to hear!

What is another way I can open and close an image without using PIL or subprocess?

Comment: Try it using OpenCV 3. Display the image using `cv2.imshow()`, wait for some time using `cv2.waitKey()` and then use `cv2.destroyWindow()` to close it. Use them sequentially within a `for loop`.

Comment: Check [THIS PAGE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) for more details.

Comment: You can also use PILasOPENCV found at https://github.com/bunkahle/PILasOPENCV . Images can be shown easily using internally opencv for it. More info on mentioned the webpage.